# How to obtain absolutely fixed line spacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-spacing, eledmac, eledpar

I use Xetex with `eledmac` and `eledpar` to produce a bilingual document with facing pages. I add some endnotes only inside the even pages.

I have a problem with corresponding paragraphs (one on the left page, one on the right page), not exactly horizontally aligned. I discovered the source of the problem. Because of the footnote references, which appear as exponent numbers, LaTeX automatically extend, just a little, the line spacing for the lines where there is exponent characters. The `eledpar` package seems not to take into account this additional line spacing. As a result, there is a ugly very small shift in the horizontal alignment.

Exemple:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
    \pstart
qqqq qqqqq qqqq qqqq qqqqq qqq qqq qqq qqqqqqq qqqqqqq qqqq qqqqq qqqqqq$^d$$^d$$^d$$^d$qqqqqqq qqqqqqqq qqqqqqqqq

    \pend
            \pstart
\blindtext[1]
    \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
  \pstart
qqqq qqqqq qqqq qqqq qqqqq qqq qqq qqq qqqqqqq qqqqqqq qqqq qqqqq qqqqqqddddqqqqqqq qqqqqqqq qqqqqqqqq
    \pend
            \pstart
\blindtext[1]

    \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

You can see that the second paragraphs are not perfectly horizontally aligned.

Is it possible in LaTeX to disable these automatic line-spacing-stretching, in order to obtain *absolutely fixed* line spacing? Or can I avoid my problem by another way?

Comment: don't you mean "vertical alignment"?  (you're describing top-to-bottom, not left-to-right.)

Comment: `\smash{$^d$$^d$$^d$$^d$}`.  Alternately, `\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing`.

Comment: Concerning the question "Did I mean 'vertical alignment'", it depends how you define it. By "horizontal alignment", I meant, concerning two paragraphs, the fact for them to be on the same horizontal line. In other words, they are horizontally aligned, in that sense, if and only if they are at the same (vertical) height. But maybe my way to express it is not the most usual.

Comment: sorry, but in you MWE you don't use the footnote reference, but some mathetical caractère. In any case, this problem is not linked to eledmac, as you can see by printing it outside of eledmac system.

Comment: It works in columns, but not pages.  The answer is deep in the interticies of eledpar.

Comment: hum, I don't see any difference between outside and inside of eledpar, but I am tired. Eledpar split each pstart with \vsplit to \baselineskip. Maybe there is something in the \vsplit operation which makes problem.

Answer (score 1):

At least with your MWE you can solve it by setting lineskip to zero (without having to set a higher baselineskip as suggested in another comment).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}%<======== here
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
    \pstart
qqqq qqqqq qqqq qqqq qqqqq qqq qqq qqq qqqqqqq qqqqqqq qqqq qqqqq qqqqqq$^d$$^d$$^d$$^d$qqqqqqq qqqqqqqq qqqqqqqqq

    \pend
            \pstart
\blindtext[1]
    \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
  \pstart
qqqq qqqqq qqqq qqqq qqqqq qqq qqq qqq qqqqqqq qqqqqqq qqqq qqqqq qqqqqqddddqqqqqqq qqqqqqqq qqqqqqqqq
    \pend
            \pstart
\blindtext[1]

    \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```